# What datatype should i choose for mysql db to store a paragraph text which includes special characters as well?

Tags: mysql, character-set

In my MySql DB I want to store some text which will be a mimimun of 1000 words, it will contain some special characters like `"",'()<>-.!;`
data will be passed using php.

Comment: `varchar` or `text` depending on the size ("words" doesn't mean anything) [see the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-types.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several datatypes that hold text. When you declare any of them you can also specify their collation and character set.  For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE mytable {
    mytext VARCHAR(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
)
```

This gives you a place to store up to 2000 characters of Unicode text. Each Unicode character can take from 1 to 4 bytes of storage. Unicode, as you know, handles many different human scripts, not to mention emojis and math symbols.

To store text you have

- the `CHAR()` data type if you know upfront exactly how many characters you must store.
- the `VARCHAR()` data type. It has best performance especially if you want to filter on it.
- the so-called [LOB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) (large object) [data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings):

  - `LONGTEXT` ... up to 4GiB in your text. This is what WordPress uses for content, for what it's worth.
  - `MEDIUMTEXT` ... up to 16MiB
  - `TEXT` ... up to 64KiB
  - `TINYTEXT` ... up to 255 bytes (useless, use `VARCHAR(255)` instead)

These all have reasonable overhead in terms of disk space used.

If you want to put indexes on `VARCHAR()` columns limit their size to `VARCHAR(768)`.

**Pro tip**: Avoid the LOB data types unless you absolutely need them. They make the server do extra work when you use them in SELECT or WHERE clauses. Use `VARCHAR()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns in a tabel) and the character set used. VARCHAR is easier to use.

TEXT data type can hold up to 64KB.
Don't forget to escape the ' character (as in \') in TEXT field data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **BLOB** datatype to store your text. it can handle up to 64KB of data which is around 64000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Mediumtext has known bugs associated with inserting into a mediumtext field, so I would recommend staying away from that, as a paragraph is not enough to warrant it.